# How to check whether the app is ever installed from google play account in android

Tags: android, android-activity, google-play-services

I want to check whether my Android app is ever installed from the current google play store account. If it was installed before, I want to make UI changes on my startup activity. Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the version code.
   PackageInfo packInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
   versionCode = packInfo.versionCode;
2. If the version code is of the previous version. Then u can do changes to the UI.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I want to do it programatically in my startup activity. Basically I need to check if it is a first time install for my app on this device or user has installed it before.

Comment: get the app version code in the activity, if its the older version then u can do the changes....

Comment: But this will return me the current version code (which I just installed). How can I find out the version code from the last build?

Answer (score 0):

`Google will not provide you the email id of users` who have installed your app.

If you want to achieve this, `you need to manage everything by yourself`.Just get account information programmatically from the device and send it to your server on starting of your app.and server should give response according to existance of that email id.

Comment: Which server you are talking about here?

Comment: your own webserver(if you have webhosting) which can store central database for you.